# Insert multiple row in one submit in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I really need help on this one. i want to allow user to multiple upload with single brows.

view is like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('TypologyPicture', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
        <legend><?php echo __('Add Picture'); ?></legend>
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('id');
        echo $this->Form->input('typology_id');
        echo $this->Form->input('pic_path', array('label'=>'Picture','type'=>'file','multiple'=>'multiple'));

    ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
</div>
```

and the controller is like this:

```
/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->TypologyPicture->create();
            if ($this->TypologyPicture->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){
            $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list');
        } else {
            $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list', array('conditions' => array('ItemTypologyPicture.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));
            }
        $this->set(compact('typologies'));
    }
```

So what i want to achieve is that when the user click browse, he can select multiple images,  and also selects a typology where this pic belonges to. so when he clicks submit all the phottos selected uploads and belonges to the typology he just selected. so how can i save all the images paths in db with just one submit??

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty clearly explained in the section of the CakePHP Book on [Saving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#saving-your-data), particularly the part on [saveAll()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)